# AWS Glue Datastore: Add individual files to partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I've got a day-partitioned s3 directory structure `s3://userlogs/year=YYYY/month=MM/day=DD/`  I've got servers constantly populating the current day's directory with files--they add about 6,000 files each day.  After each file is added, I want to update a table `userlogs` in the Glue Datastore to include it.

The problem is that AWS glue only gives us a way of adding entirely new partitions (and their corresponding directories) to a table with a command like

```
ALTER TABLE userlogs ADD
  PARTITION (year = '2016', month = '01', day = '01) LOCATION 's3://userlogs/year=2016/month=01/day=02/'
```

However, each time I run that command I assume Glue needs to scan all of the potentially thousands of files in that directory.

What I'd really like is some kind of method/command that would do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE userlogs UPDATE
  PARTITION (year = '2016', month = '01', day = '01) ADD FILE's3://userlogs/year=2016/month=01/day=02/todays_file_no_3423.parquet.gz'
```

Is there any way of achieving this goal that doesn't involve restructuring how I store my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command `ALTER TABLE ...` doesn't scan you data in S3 (so it is free of charge). It simply defines meta information about you data in AWS Glue Data Catalog, i.e. location of files in S3 that should be searchable with Athena queries, therefore, it takes less then a second to for this command to finish.

Thus, You don't need to add files individually as long as you have defined/created a partition in glue metastore that "points" to the location in S3 where those files reside. So after

```sql
ALTER TABLE userlogs ADD 
PARTITION (year = '2016', month = '01', day = '01') 
LOCATION 's3://userlogs/year=2016/month=01/day=01/';
```

You can add as many files to `s3://userlogs/year=2016/month=01/day=01/` and all their content would be available to query through Athena.

### Additional notes TL;DR

Not sure, whether the following behaviour of `ALTER TABLE userlogs ADD PARTITION ...` is how it supposed to be, but:

- It only checks whether S3 bucket exists, but not the full S3 path. So the following DDL statements will succeed

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE userlogs ADD 
  PARTITION (..., day='01')    LOCATION 's3://userlogs/year=2016/month=01/day=01/'
  PARTITION (..., day='wrong') LOCATION 's3://userlogs/year=2016/month=01/day=wrong_path/';
  ```

  Normal queries would also succeed but with different results since there are no files in wrong path

  ```sql
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userlogs WHERE day = '01'     -- outputs some value
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userlogs WHERE day = 'wrong'  -- outputs 0
  ```
- It doesn't check whether you have permission to that location.

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE userlogs ADD 
  PARTITION (..., day='01')         LOCATION 's3://userlogs/year=2016/month=01/day=01/'
  PARTITION (..., day='restricted') LOCATION 's3://userlogs/year=2016/month=01/day=restricted/';
  ```

  This means that a single partition in meta store that points to such location could fail `SELECT`

  ```sql
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userlogs  --  error(s): Access Denied ...
  ```

  Unless you exclude it in `WHERE` clause:

  ```sql
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userlogs WHERE day != 'restricted'
  ```

  or delete this partition with `DROP PARTITION`

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE userlogs DROP PARTITION (..., day='restricted');
  -- Followed by, which will succeed
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userlogs
  ```
- Partition values doesn't have be that same as in location (this is sort of expected) and different values can be used to point to the same location at the same time.

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE userlogs ADD 
  PARTITION (..., day='01')    LOCATION 's3://userlogs/year=2016/month=01/day=01/'
  PARTITION (..., day='first') LOCATION 's3://userlogs/year=2016/month=01/day=01/';
  ```

  Now if we query using `WHERE` clause, we will get the same result.

  ```sql
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userlogs WHERE day = '01'   
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userlogs WHERE day = 'first'
  ```

  Let's assume that both of them output **10**. However, if you query without `WHERE` clause, then the output will be **20** since Athena scanned the same location twice.

Comment: So the Glue Data Catalog does not contain file-level stats?  Does that mean when I run a query on a folder that has thousands of files, performance will grind to a halt because some process needs to list all those files in s3, and read in parquet metadata?

Comment: Yes, you will hit an I/O bottleneck as the number of files grow. However, `SNAPPY` compression supposed to provide better IO compared to `GZIP` for example. Nevertheless, it is not advised to have a lot of small files, try to stick to 128MB - 1GB file size. You can use [`CTAS`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html) queries to overcome this. As for file-level stats in glue catalog not sure. `ALTER TABLE` most surely wouldn't do that, but use of glue crawler might.